# background-size: cover is not working to completely fill div with background-image

Tags: html, css

I would like for the background image to fill the div that contains it. I will attach pictures to show what's happening.

What is the cause of this empty space? It is preventing me from moving my containers closer together.

Here is a codepen link: http://codepen.io/ManBearPigg/full/qZVJWy/

```
#firstContainer {
  background-image: url("/focusbackground.png");
  background-size: cover;
  width: 720px;
  height: 700px;
  float: left;
  margin-left: -7%;
}

#secondContainer {
  background-image: url("/focusbackground.png");
  background-size: cover;
  width: 720px;
  height: 700px;
  float:right;
  margin-right: 5%;
}
```

Here is the html

```
<div id="container">
  <div id="firstContainer">
    <form id="firstForm" action="">
      <textarea id="firstArea" type="text" onkeypress="return myKeyPress(event)"></textarea>
      <input type="submit" id="firstSubmit"></input>
      <div id="lineNo"></div>
    </form>
  </div>
  <div id="secondContainer">
    <form id="secondForm" action="">
      <textarea id="secondArea" type="text" onkeypress="return mySecondKeyPress(event)"></textarea>
      <input type="submit" id="secondSubmit"></input>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: From your picture, I am still unclear of what the issue is. Perhaps you could provide a second picture that demonstrates what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Jsfiddle or codepen will always be better than pictures

Comment: I think a picture of what I want to achieve would mean that my problem would have been solved. I can explain further though. I want the background image to completely fill the div. Currently, it only partially fills the div, and then blank space carries on to the border. That blank space is occupying useful real estate that I would like to use. I want to get rid of that blank space. The borders of my background image are the exact borders of the mock chrome windows.

Comment: I provided a codepen. If you open the console and inspect the elements you can see what I mean

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe this is more a comment than an answer but I can´t add a comment on your post, so I apologise in case I did not understand your problem.

What I can see is that your [image](http://s9.postimg.org/4laackvcf/focusbackground.png) itself has a white border. You probably need to cut the image to remove the parts without the picture. By doing that, it will cover the div

Comment: I used OSX preview to select outside the image, deleted it, then saved as png. This left invisible white space. Thanks for checking the image in browser where the white space was visible and I was able to fix my problem

Answer (score 0):

@will is correct. The image you are using is an actual image file and as such will have certain properties that are difficult or not worth the bother to manipulate via HTML, CSS, JavaScript, etc. Some files like images, audio, and video need editing or converting before it is uploaded. That image for instance, needs that transparent area cropped. I did the following:

1. Downloaded the PNG image file.
2. Used [Paint.NET](http://www.getpaint.net/index.html) program to crop the transparent area of the file.
3. Uploaded file to [imgur](http://imgur.com/).
4. Replaced the url: http://s9.postimg.org/4laackvcf/focusbackground.png with the new one from imgur: https://i.stack.imgur.com/MjlMx.png

   ```
   body {
       background:#628fd5;
   }

   #firstContainer {
       background-image: url("https://i.stack.imgur.com/MjlMx.png");
       background-size: cover;
       width: 720px;
       height: 700px;
       float: left;
       margin-left: -7%;
    }

    #secondContainer {
       background-image: url("https://i.stack.imgur.com/MjlMx.png");
       background-size: cover;
       width: 720px;
       height: 700px;
       float:right;
       margin-right: 5%;
    }
   ```

The result is at this [**CodePen**](http://codepen.io/zer00ne/pen/grXBKr).

Btw, I replaced the blue image with `body { background:#628fd5; }`. It's always better to use CSS than it is to use a file. For every image you have on a page is a HTTP request round trip which adds to latency (slows down your webpage/site).